# Grails 2 GORM with custom id field complaining of "Provided id of the wrong type for class" in show action

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2 to provide an interface on a legacy database with custom id fields.

I have a domain class like the following:

```
class StorageFile {

static mapping = {
  table 'storage_file'
  // version is set to false, because this column isn't normally present in legacy databases
  version false

  id generator:'identity', name:'fileId', column:'file_id'
  objectIdStorageObject column:'object_id'
}

Integer fileId
StorageObject objectIdStorageObject

static constraints = {
  fileId(max: 2147483647)
  objectIdStorageObject()
}

String toString() {
  return "${fileId}" 
}
```

I generated the controller and view with scaffolding. The links in the view generated don't work because of the following item:

`<td><g:link action="show" id="${storageFileInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: storageFileInstance, field: "fileId")}</g:link></td>`

though I can fix that by replacing with `id=${storageFileInstance.id}` with `id=${storageFileInstance.fileId}` .

There is another problem which then shows up, and is evident even if I just manually go to 
a url like /TestTmm/StorageFile/show/362 . Grails generates an error like:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI /TestTmm/storageFile/show/362
Class org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException
Message Provided id of the wrong type for class tmmweb.StorageFile. 
  Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long`
```

The params.id itself provided to the controller show action in the following:

```
def show() {
  def storageFileInstance = StorageFile.get(params.id)
```

is a String, which I can check with `println "${params.id.getClass()}`, but somehow this is ending up in Hibernate as a Long, rather than an Integer. It is quite unclear why?

A similar class where the id field is named 'id' doesn't have this problem.

```
class Role {

  static mapping = {
    table 'role'
    version false

    usersList column:'rid',joinTable:'users_roles'
    id generator:'identity', column:'rid'
  }

  Integer id
  String name

  static hasMany = [ usersList : User ]
  static belongsTo = [User]

  static constraints = {
    id(max: 2147483647)
    name(size: 1..64, blank: false)
    usersList()
  }

  String toString() {
    return "${name}" 
  }

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix what must be a problem with the hibernate mapping that is occurring?

Comment: Some further experiments:If I change the type of the field to with `Long fileId`, then there is no error. This is even the case if I set the type of the column in the mapping block to 'integer'. So it appears that the StorageFile.get method that is generated must somehow be converting to Long before the mapping.

Comment: May be a bug, so I just filed a jira report on it: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9375

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should define the name of the id to be anything else than 'id'. You can add an alias for the id property if you really want to access it with another name.

```
class StorageFile {
static mapping = {
  table 'storage_file'
  // version is set to false, because this column isn't normally present in legacy databases
  version false

  id generator:'identity', column:'file_id'
  objectIdStorageObject column:'object_id'
}

Integer id
StorageObject objectIdStorageObject

// if you want to add an alias for "id"
static transients = ['fileId']

public Integer getFileId() { id }
```

Comment: Yes, an alias certainly can work, thanks, though I would prefer to just be able to use an id of another name. There are many references in the Grails documentation to be able to do this with the hibernate mapping, yet it doesn't work. Seems like the bug should be fixed in Grails or it should clearly indicate you cannot change the name of the actual field from 'id'.